# Time profiler doesn't show me functions

Tags: ios, swift, instruments

In tutorial, when someone debug app they see something like this:

[image]

But when i start recording, by pressing red button:

[image]

I see this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the Generate Debug Symbols build setting is set to Yes. You need debug symbols to have function names appear in Instruments.

If your project is generating debug symbols, Instruments may not be able to find your project's dSYM file. In Instruments choose Instrument > Call Tree Data Mining > Locate dSYM file to find and open your project's dSYM file. Your project's dSYM file is usually located in the same directory as the application bundle of your project's release version. Additional information can be found in the following article:

[Instruments: Locating dSYM Files](http://meandmark.com/blog/2016/02/instruments-locating-dsym-files/)

Answer (score 4):

I had 2 different versions of Xcode 9.4.1 and 10.1 both of them had command line tools which were in conflict(i suppose). To fix this issue I set right command line tools version there:

"Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations tab -> Command line tools".

[image: xcode Preferences]

Also check Build Settings and set "DWARF with dSYM File" to your target.

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: I installed the Xcode 11 beta and the command line tools were still set to Xcode 10. Setting them to Xcode 11 fixed it for me. Thank you!