# Stacktrace not symbolized when run leak test with Xcode Instruments

Tags: ios, stack-trace, instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm using Xcode 8 Instruments to find leaks, but the stack trace is not symbolized, and I already set to Debug mode when Profiling, what else should I do?

[image: profile in debug mode]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the following question: [Time profiler doesn't show me functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527164/time-profiler-doesnt-show-me-functions)