# How to solve memory leaks from instruments?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I can see some memory leaks in my code, if i run from the instruments. But in call tree, I'm not getting proper information about memory leak.

How can we identify and solve those kind of memory leaks .

[image]

Comment: Read the answer to the following question: [Time profiler doesn't show me functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527164/time-profiler-doesnt-show-me-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the memory graph tool for debugging which XCode 8.x contains. There is a WWDC talk which includes it (along with other debugging elements) that is [located here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/410/).

You can also search "memory graph debugger xcode" in your favorite search engine to learn more (I could include links but they are not guaranteed to be around).