# It doesn't seem to main in Time Profiler - Xcode 9.1

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

It doesn't seem to main in Time Profiler - Xcode 9.1

Profile should look like this:

[image]

But it seems that way:

[image]

I have 2 iPads. I can see "main" one but I don't see in the other ipad. I don't understand what the difference. 
Are need to make an adjustment on the iPad?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time profiler doesn't show me functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36527164/time-profiler-doesnt-show-me-functions)

Answer (score 0):

this way, when you change the iPad's settings solved the problem.

on the `Settings>Developer>Instruments>Logging` 
screen change `Energy = True`